# clang-format: Formatting struct fields (like Linux kernel)

Tags: clang, clang-format

Is it possible to format the C struct fields (as in Linux kernel) so that the field all the variable NAMEs are aligned as are their TYPEs. Instead, what I get is the TYPEs and NAMEs separated by just one space.

For example (expected):

```
struct napi_struct {
         struct list_head        poll_list;
         unsigned long           state;
         int                     weight;
         unsigned int            gro_count;
         int                     (*poll)(struct napi_struct *, int);
         struct net_device       *dev;
         struct sk_buff          *gro_list;
         struct sk_buff          *skb;
         struct hrtimer          timer;
         struct list_head        dev_list;
         struct hlist_node       napi_hash_node;
         unsigned int            napi_id;
};
```

What are the clang-format parameters to be set to get such formatting?

Comment: Can you try "AlignConsecutiveDeclarations" option as true? (found in http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html)

Comment: I guess it does not work on version 3.6. The 3.9 does not seem to be available in latest of distros yet.

Comment: On newer versions of clang-format, `AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: true` will do *most* of what you're asking for. Unfortunately, the function pointer in your struct confuses it, so you get the fields before the function pointer aligned, and the fields after the function pointer aligned, but the groups don't align with each other.